# The elementId is null after the second time the component has been initialized

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I have a component where I will draw a canvas chart. And when I initialize the component for the first time, everything is ok, but if I leave this component and return to it again, then document.getElementById('myChart'); is null and doesn't draw my chart

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    this.Chart(); 
}


private Chart() {
    const ctx: any = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), { // some shit })
}
```

I tried to do it differently

```
 const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myChart');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

But I didn't quite understand how to solve this error and eventually came to the first option

```
Argument of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartItem'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ChartItem'.
```

Comment: what if you try to change ```ngAfterViewInit()``` to ```ngOnInit()``` ?

Comment: @KibéM.C I tried everywhere but nothing helps, i just thought that the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle is initialized after the dom tree

Comment: do this: replace your ```ngAfterViewInit()``` funtion with ```ngOnInit(): void {Chart.register(...registerables);
    this.Chart(); 
}```

Comment: I tried, same problem @KibéM.C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached this problem from a different angle.
First I used ViewChild and applied ElementRef to it

```
  @ViewChild('myChart') chartRef: ElementRef;
  private myChart: Chart;
```

And be sure to use everything in ngAfterViewInit since it starts working after building the DOM tree

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.Chart();
  }

 this.myChart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {some shit})
```